# regular expression in R - extract words

Tags: r, regex

suppose I have the next string.

```
"col1 xx > col2 xx xx > col3 > col4 xx xx > col5"

How can I extract the first word before the first ">" (col1)
Or the first word before the second ">" (col2)
Or the first word before the third ">" (col3) ..
```

Comment: So what's the rule? You want to extract values that start with the letters "col". Just ignore "xx xx" values? Why not just split on ">"?

Comment: chuck up your attempt and we'll help you get it fixed up :)

Comment: Nono, this is just an example. It is very important to discriminate each word before a ">"

Comment: a<-"col1 xx > col2 xx xx > col3 > col4 xx xx > col5"
strsplit(unlist(strsplit(a,">"))[1]," ","")[[1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the input is

```
x <- "col1 xx > col2 xx xx > col3 > col4 xx xx > col5"
```

Then here are some alternatives:

**1) strsplit**  Split the string on a space followed by the shortest string of any characters followed by a > and a space.  No packages are used.

```
strsplit(x, " .*?> ")[[1]]
## [1] "col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5"
```

**2) strapply** This repeatedly matches a word `"(\\w+)"` followed by the shortest sequence of characters `".*?"` until either a > or the end `"(>|$)"` returning the words.

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(x, "(\\w+).*?(>|$)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
## [1] "col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5"
```

**3) strapplyc** If we knew that the words we want all consist of lower case letters followed by numbers and no other words of that form exist then this would work:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(x, "[a-z]+\\d+")[[1]]
## [1] "col1" "col2" "col3" "col4" "col5"
```